# Getting the position of the element in a list when it's drag/dropped (ui.sortable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, position, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list like this one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable

Is it possible to get the start and end position of the element in the list, when it has been moved? I'm talking about their position number, in the list.

For example, if I move element 2 to position 5 in the list, I'd like to assign those two numbers to variables.

I'm new to jQuery - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is such a great example of the terrible API design of jQuery UI

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/getting-the-position-of-the-element-in-a-list-when-its-drag-dropped-ui-sortable/

SOLUTION:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul#sortable').sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            var start_pos = ui.item.index();
            ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
            var end_pos = ui.item.index();
            alert(start_pos + ' - ' + end_pos);
        }
    });
});
```

> - **NOTE:** Updated to make use of jQuery [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method under advice of [Alconja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68727/alconja)

Comment: +1 Nice concise answer, but you don't need to wrap the `ui.item`, it's already a jQuery object. So instead of `$(ui.item)` use `ui.item`

Comment: Elegant answer! Thank you so much.
I guess the ui.item object is what I was looking for, here.

Comment: +1, although you should probably use `ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);` in `start` and `var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');` in `update` rather than polluting the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking to do is done with the [serialize method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize). Serialize is get the new order of the list.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `ui.item.index()` did not work for me.

This did:

```
update: function (event, ui) 
{
    var index = $('li', $(ui.item).parent()).index(ui.item);
    alert(index);
}
```