# jquery ui multiple drops problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, droppable

I have 2 droppable divs and when a drag is dropped on either one of them, i'm trying to get the id of that drop element. It's always returning the id of the first drop element in the DOM.

```
$('#albumImgs li').draggable({
  containment: '#content',
  scrollSensitivity: 60,
  revert: 'invalid',
  cursor: 'move'
});

$('.dropContainerClosed').droppable({
  accept: '#albumImgs li',
  activeClass: 'dropContainerOpen',
  drop: function(event, ui) {

    var file = $(ui.draggable.find('img'));
    var fileName = file.attr('alt');

    var albumName = $('div.dropContainerClosed').attr('id');

    console.log("fileName = "+fileName);
    console.log("albumName = "+albumName);//always returns the first div.dropContainerClosed id in the DOM

    if(albumName != undefined) {
        $.post('addImage.php', {filen: fileName, albumn: albumName}, 
      function(data) {
        //do something here
      }, 'json');
    } else {
        $.post('firstImage.php', {filen: fileName, albumn: albumName}, 
      function(data) {
        //do something here
      }, 'json');
    }           
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ui.item.attr('id');`

se my similar responce on this question!

> [Getting the position of the element in a list when it's drag/dropped (ui.sortable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442232/getting-the-position-of-the-element-in-a-list-when-its-drag-dropped-ui-sortable/2443081#2443081)

```
    $(function() {
    $my_droppable = $('#my_droppable');

    $my_droppable.droppable({
              accept: '#my_droppable > li',
              activeClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
              drop: function(ev, ui) {
    //define your func after drop..
                get_my_attr(ui.draggable);
              }
            });

//THIS IS IMPORTANT FOR GET THE ATTR AND OTHER STUFF

// resolve the icons behavior with event delegation

        $('ul.my_droppable > li').click(function(ev) {
          var $item = $(this);
          var $target = $(ev.target);

          if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-trash')) {
            deleteImage($item);
          } else if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-zoomin')) {
            viewLargerImage($target);
          } else if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-refresh')) {
            recycleImage($item);
          }

          return false;
        });

      });
    });
            function get_my_attr($item) {

              alert($item.attr('class'));

            }
```

Comment: I'm getting ui.item undefined when i try this

var albumName = ui.item.attr('id');
console.log("albumName = ".albumName);

Comment: Also can you point me in the direction of the documentation for ui. whatever?

Comment: are you sure that all your Li's have an id? ui.item work only for selected item! ( LI )

Comment: I'm not actually using sortable though and it doesn't look like the droppable widget uses ui.item. http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager  I'll just have to create a separate droppable declaration for each drop area.