# Jquery draggable persistence either through mysql or saving cookie in the database?

Tags: jquery-ui, persistence, draggable, drag-and-drop

I want to know that how can I persist the divs dropped on a draggable. I have been trying since long but stuck at this point. Actually you can see the [demo](http://webwide.byethost18.com/final%20test/design_floor.php) here. I have to save the user designed wedding floor. So whenever user logins next time he/ she is able to see the last design saved. The code is shown below:

```
                                             $(document).ready(function() {
                                                $("#droppable").droppable({
                                                    accept: '.draggable',
                                                    drop: function(event, ui) {
                                                            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
                                                            $("#droppable .draggable").addClass("objects");
                                                            $(".objects").removeClass("ui-draggable draggable");
                                                            $(".objects").draggable({
                                                                    containment: 'parent',
                                                            });
                                                    }
                                                });
                                                $(".draggable").draggable({
                                                    helper: 'clone',
                                                    tolerance: 'touch',
                                                    cursor:'move'
                                                });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Get Position of each Object ([easy](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to do with JQuery)
2. Serialize to JSON and save to a database of your choice. Don't use cookies for this.

Comment: do you use mysql as a database? on what do you need an example, the database connection part? the serialization?

Comment: Yes i use mysql as the db. I want to know the actual code to pass the data from jquery to php using json. Furthermore what I have to do after passing those values in php code to save those values in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I have already asked to this kind of question read this:

[jQuery UI sortable: determining in what order the items are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669130/jquery-ui-sortable-determining-in-what-order-the-items-are/2669215#2669215)

and this:

[Getting the position of the element in a list when it's drag/dropped (ui.sortable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442232/getting-the-position-of-the-element-in-a-list-when-its-drag-dropped-ui-sortable/2443081#2443081)

hope this help

Comment: I want to know the actual code to pass the data from jquery to php using json. Furthermore what I have to do after passing those values in php code to save those values in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice tutorial and demo of how to drag-and-drop with PHP,jQuery-UI and MySQL here: [PaperMashup](http://papermashup.com/drag-drop-with-php-jquery/)