# Saving the results of a drag and drop list

Tags: php, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

Ok, full disclosure. I'm BRAND new here. This is my first question. My coding skills are weak but I'm learning.

I've taken on a charity project. We have a pretty standard HTML form to complete, but it has a section for language and we want to ask folks to re-order the languages -- drag and drop -- to indicate their fluency.

I then need all the fields (Name, Email Address, Language Preferences) to be emailed to me.

I can create the form; I can create the drag and drop, but I cannot figure out how to pass the contents of the reordered list.

```
<body>
<header>
<h1>Preferences Form</h1>
</header>
<BR><BR>
<center>
   <form method="post" action="process.php">>
   <label>Your Name:</label>
   <input name="name" placeholder="Goes Here">
   <label>Your Email:</label>
   <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Goes Here">

</center>
<section>
<h2>Language Fluency - Reorder Please</h2>
    <ul id="Language" class="handles list">
        <li><span>:: </span>English</li>
        <li><span>:: </span>French</li>
        <li><span>:: </span>German</li>
        <li><span>:: </span>Spanish</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Volunteer Country</h2>
    <ul id="Country" class="handles list">
        <li><span>:: </span>Peru</li>
        <li><span>:: </span>Eritrea</li>
        <li><span>:: </span>Equatorial Guinea</li>
        <li><span>:: </span>Haiti</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sortable.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('.sortable').sortable();
$('.handles').sortable({
    handle: 'span'
        });
        $('.connected').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connected'
        });
        $('.exclude').sortable({
            items: ':not(.disabled)'
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The process.php I'm using once the submit is hit is pretty simple.

```
<?php
// Get Data 
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

// Here I cannot work out the field/vars for the UIs if it's even possible

// Send Message
mail( "email@email.com", "Preferences List",
"Name: $name\nEmail: $email\n",
"From: Volunteer <do-not-reply@fakeemail.com>" );

echo "Sent, thanks!"

?>
```

So to be clear and repeat: How do I pass the contents of the two re-ordered lists to email? If at all possible, I'd like to avoid mysql or dbase solutions as that will be yet another code to learn, but I will if I have to.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

J

Comment: Use something to the affect of `<select size="1" name="language[]"><option>option_1</option><option>option_2</option><option>option_3</option></select>` for your `language` options, then in your processor use `$language = strip_tags($_POST['language']);` and so on.

Comment: Fred, I think that may be what sortable() is doing, but it is hard to tell. Jonathan, put `print_r($_POST)` on your proccess.php to see if it's actually being submitted.

Comment: Fred, thanks, but that creates a dropdown list, not a drag and drop? And it only allows a single selection whereas I'd like to capture the order of those four languages.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought that's what was required. I misinterpreted the question then.

Comment: Connor - No data from the UIs. That's my challenge. I'm seeing only name/email

Comment: ok, I think this might do it: save the results as a cookie and then write the vars back to email, onclick. Thoughts?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669130/jquery-ui-sortable-determining-in-what-order-the-items-are

Comment: feel free to accept your favorite answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript to store the list results into a hidden field. Bind it to the submit button.

For example:
You have two lists: `#columns` and `#selected_columns`.

HTML:

```
<input id='saved_columns' type='hidden' name='TableColumns' />

<ul class='sortable' id='columns'>
    <li data-itemid='FirstName'>First Name</li>
    <li data-itemid='LastName'>Last Name</li>
    <li data-itemid='DayPhone'>Day Phone</li>
    <li data-itemid='Email'>Email</li>
</ul>

<ul class='sortable' id='selected_columns'>
</ul>
```

and use something like this for your javascript:
(I'm using jQuery List DragSort http://dragsort.codeplex.com/)

```
$("#columns,#selected_columns").dragsort({
    dragSelector: "li", 
    dragBetween: true, 
    dragEnd: saveOrder, 
    placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'></li>"
});

function saveOrder() {
    var data = $("#selected_columns li").map(function() { 
        return $(this).data("itemid");
    }).get();
    $('#saved_columns').val(data);
}
```

As you can see, DragSort is using a callback (saveOrder) each time an element is dragged-and-dropped. saveOrder takes the `itemid` from each item in the drop list and stores them into the hidden field `#saved_columns`.