# Dragable and Sortable Item Number Update on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Following is my fiddle in which I am able to drag my list items but the issue is on changing the position of the list item i am not able to sort the number of items accordingly for example if I change the position of item # 1 then the number of all items doesnot change from top to bottom. Kindly let me know how to do it.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eEJHb/14/)**

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
      $("ul").append("<li class='ui-state-default'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span><input type='text' value='New Item : #' /></li>");
  });
});
```

Comment: dont seee #drop anywhere ?? what number are u trying to change

Comment: @wilsonrufus all I want is to set the item number as per li position for example if i put the 1st li to second position then item number of all the lis should change accordingly

Comment: will this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669130/jquery-ui-sortable-determining-in-what-order-the-items-are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
        //observe the update event...
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = [];
            $('#sortable li').each(function (e) {
                $(this).attr("value",$(this).index());

            });
        }
    });
```

I have added the value attribute to li which will be updated whenver the ul is sorted

Comment: This is not working value attr is adding but not changing as per their position also the value on the text field is not updating

Comment: oh u wanted the text also to change check again the fiddle is this what u wanted now even the input value will change It is the same link