# Change colour of items in jquery sortable list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm making a simple quiz/game using jQuery UI sortable for kids. I want to get the user to sort the list into what they think is the correct order and then press a button to check their answer...then colour correct items green and incorrect as red.

So, my main question is how to I check through the list and colour the items.

I can't find a way to colour the items dynamically; and not sure if there is an easy way built into jQuery to check the order.

Note: I do not want to do the checking server side so assume something inside the script identifies the correct order (I know it could allow cheating but I'm not worried about that!).

I am VERY new to jQuery! :)

**EDIT - Think I have a solution....**

I think I've done it. My code is below. I used this [code as my baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442232/getting-the-position-of-the-element-in-a-list-when-its-drag-dropped-ui-sortabl/2443081#2443081) then added in the colour stuff using .addClass() and .removeClass(). Is this method OK? (The code is a bit rough and ready; it's the methodology that I'm not sure is the best).

```
$(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        var result = $('#sortable').sortable('toArray');
        var correct = new Array("1","0","2","3","4","5","6");
        var myID;

        for (n=0;n<7;n++)
        {
            myID = "#" + n;
                $( String(myID) ).removeClass( "correct" );
                $( String(myID) ).removeClass( "wrong" );
        }

        for (i=0;i<result.length;i++)
        {

            if (result[i] == correct[i])
            {
                myID = "#" + result[i];
                $( String(myID) ).addClass( "correct" );
            }
            else
            {
                myID = "#" + result[i];
                $( String(myID) ).addClass( "wrong" );
            }

        }

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Please post [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) already.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?
Try using the sort event to alert the current position, and see if it changes. You can see the position using something like 
var alert='' 
$(selector).each(function(){ alert += ', '+$(this).attr('class');});

Comment: Looks ok. However storing the correct sequence on the java script side  in a static manner can reveal the answers to the users even before they attempt them a single time. Users can view source or open dev tools to find out.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a logical question.

create a css class "error" and another one "Correct" with red background and green background respectively, like below.

```
.error {   background-color: red;}
.correct {   background-color: green;}
```

pseudo code consider general MVC pattern [HttpPost] represents a HTTP POST FORM request 
I assume your controller name is QuizController and then actions are:

```
public ActionResult RenderPuzzle(int id)
{
  return view(....);//modeled with list of options sorted with class set to "correct" for each sortable list element in view for the puzzle option.
}

{HttpPost]
public ActionResult RenderPuzzle(Option opts, int id)
{
    //check if model state is valid then check the ordering and set the class to error for wrong ordered list elements and also you can display the correct order adjacent to it. Form your view accordingly
    return view(...);
}
```

You can also do this through ajax which will take more efforts from your side. With ajax you need to apply partial business logic at the client side also and use jquery method to apply classes (error and correct) to the sortable elements. The actual results can be pulled with ajax request and then compared with the sortable list state order.