# How to show a message when all pieces are in the right order?

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a web mobile app for children to learn the alphabet (that's a school project). I have done an exercise based on jquery ui. With this exercise children are able to move the pieces of a cut picture. The pieces are 30, 26 of them have a letter. So the first image is A than the second B.... and when all of them are in the right order a picture is formed. I have done a function for randomizing them each time when the page is refreshed. What I want to make is that, I want when all pieces are in the right order to be showed a message.
So that's my jquery code.

```
$( "h1" ).click(function(){
    $( this ).slideUp();
});

$.fn.randomize = function(selector){
var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
    $parents = $elems.parent();

$parents.each(function(){
    $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
        return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
    }).detach().appendTo(this);
});

return this;
};

$( "#sortable" ).randomize();   
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({ 
    cursor: "help" 
}); 
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

That's the html

```
        <ul id="sortable">       
        <li class="ui-state-A">A</li>   

        <li class="ui-state-B">B</li>

        <li class="ui-state-C">C</li>

        <li class="ui-state-D">D</li>

        <li class="ui-state-E">E</li>

        <li class="ui-state-F">F</li>

        <li class="ui-state-G">G</li>

        <li class="ui-state-H">H</li>

        <li class="ui-state-I">I</li>

        <li class="ui-state-J">J</li>

        <li class="ui-state-K">K</li>

        <li class="ui-state-L">L</li>

        <li class="ui-state-M">M</li>

        <li class="ui-state-N">N</li>

        <li class="ui-state-O">O</li>

        <li class="ui-state-P">P</li>

        <li class="ui-state-Q">Q</li>

        <li class="ui-state-R">R</li>

        <li class="ui-state-S">S</li>

        <li class="ui-state-T">T</li>

        <li class="ui-state-U">U</li>

        <li class="ui-state-V">V</li>

        <li class="ui-state-W">W</li>

        <li class="ui-state-X">X</li>

        <li class="ui-state-Y">Y</li>

        <li class="ui-state-Z">Z</li>

        <li class="ui-state-1">&nbsp;</li>

        <li class="ui-state-2">&nbsp;</li>

        <li class="ui-state-3">&nbsp;</li>

        <li class="ui-state-4">&nbsp;</li>        
    </ul>
```

Thanks for the help!!! :)

Comment: There is a lot of missing code here. Are you sure you develop this already ? or you are expecting us to develop it for you ?

Comment: What do you mean by "missing code"? That's a simple code for sorting and randomizing those images. I want to make all the pieces to have a position so when all images are in its position to show a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement that on the `update` callback of the sortable plugin by iterating through all the letters in alphabet(using character code):

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {

            var positions = []; 

            // we iterate through alphabet from letter A
            var current_letter_code = 65;

            // loop through all the items
            $('#sortable li').each( function(e) {

                if(String.fromCharCode(current_letter_code) == $(this).text()){

                    current_letter_code++;

                    // if we finished all the letters, show alert
                    if(current_letter_code == 91){
                        alert('the letters are in the right order');
                    }
                } else {
                    // break the loop
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }
});
```

This code expects that the first element on li is `A` and continues to `Z` without having any `&nbsp;` in between.

---

Another way is to use `start` and `update` callback to save the positions of the letters when they change and than check if you are on the right state (all your positions of the letters are correct). A helpful link for that is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442232/getting-the-position-of-the-element-in-a-list-when-its-drag-dropped-ui-sortabl/2443081#2443081).

Comment: I tried that code but it doesn't work.. When all elements are in the right order doesn't show a message.

Comment: okay, I fixed a bug on the answer. But, try to understand the code instead of copy pasting it.

Comment: It works now, thank you for the help. I want to understand the code because I am actually interested of web programming. Thanks again :)